# how to set max of opened details in html?

Tags: javascript, html

what this code does is set the max of opened details to 1 what I want is to set it to 3 I haven't found an answer yet

```js
            const details = document.querySelectorAll("details");
            details.forEach((targetDetail) => {
                targetDetail.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    details.forEach((detail) => {
                        if (detail !== targetDetail) {
                            detail.removeAttribute("open");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

```html
       <details>
            <summary>test0</summary>
            0
        </details>
     
        <details>
            <summary>test1</summary>
            1
        </details>
        <details>
            <summary>test2</summary>
            2
        </details>
         <details>
            <summary>test3</summary>
            3
        </details>
```

Comment: suppose that I opened test0, test1, test2 when I clicked on test3 which one of the opened details should be close?

Comment: test0 should close after having 1,2 and 3 opened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution is to keep track of the nodeList indexes with an Array. I made one for you called openDetails. Then when u open a detail it gets added to the array.
When u close it, it gets removed.
When u have 3 items u can check the first item of the list, close the corresponding detail and then remove it from the list.

```js
let openDetails = [];

const details = document.querySelectorAll("details");

details.forEach((targetDetail, index) => {
  targetDetail.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const detailIsOpen = openDetails.includes(index);

    if (detailIsOpen) {
      openDetails = openDetails.filter((item) => item !== index);
    } else {

      if (openDetails.length > 2) {
        const indexToClose = openDetails[0];
        openDetails = openDetails.filter((item, i) => i !== 0);
        details[indexToClose].removeAttribute("open");
      }

      openDetails.push(index);
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>test0</summary>
  0
</details>

<details>
  <summary>test1</summary>
  1
</details>
<details>
  <summary>test2</summary>
  2
</details>
<details>
  <summary>test3</summary>
  3
</details>
```

Comment: Please make sure to always hit the "Tidy" button to properly format your code.

Comment: Thank you, you are a real legend.

Comment: ah thanks, I will! :) 
@O_N_K Your welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this,

```
  const details = document.querySelectorAll("details");
            details.forEach((targetDetail) => {
                targetDetail.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    details.forEach((detail) => {
                        if (detail !== targetDetail) {
                            detail.removeAttribute("open");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Try This One, might work for you

```
 const details = document.querySelectorAll("details");
    details.forEach((targetDetail) => {
        targetDetail.addEventListener("click", () => {
            details.forEach((detail) => {
                if (detail !== targetDetail) {
                    details.forEach(element => {
                        element.removeAttribute("open");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).